# Identificar cuantos elementos existen del tipo '.cards' y dependiendo de eso alterar una clase de css

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

Quiero saber cuantos elementos existen con `document.querySelectorAll(".card").lenght` y en el caso de que hayan 7 quisiera haya una funcion que modifique el css poniendole al contenedor que es `.card-container` un `overflow-y: scroll;` haciendo que esto se vea mucho mejor. Estoy trabajando con Nextjs , espero me puedan ayudar.

Codigo:

```
export default function Index({cards})  {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <Head>
                <title>OWO</title>
            </Head>
            <Sidebar />
            <div className='props-container'>
                <div className='nav-title'>
                    <div className='title'>Cards</div>
                    {/* <div className='switch'>
                        <input type='checkbox'/>
                    </div> */}
                </div>
                <div className='card-container'>
                        {
                            cards.map(card => (
                                <div  key={card._id} className='card'>
                                    <div className='container-c'>
                                        <div className='card-head' >{card.title}</div>
                                        <div className='card-body' ><div className='copy'>Copy</div><div className='card-names'>URL: </div> {card.url}</div>
                                        <div className='card-body' ><div className='copy'>Copy</div><div className='card-names'>ID: </div> {card.id}</div>
                                        <div className='card-body' ><div className='copy'>Copy</div><div className='card-names'>Password: </div> {card.password}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='btn-container'>
                                        <div className='btn btn-delete'>Delete</div>
                                        <div className='btn btn-edit'>Edit</div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            ))
                        }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Resultado:
[image: resultado]

Como espero que quede:
[image: resultado esperado]

Comment: Hablas de `.container-cards` y `.cards`, pero tu código usa `cards-container` y `card` como nombres de clase. ¿Puedes aclarar eso un poco?

Comment: Asi --> [...document.querySelectorAll(".cards")].lenght

Comment: En todo caso `.length`, no `.lenght`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En mi opinion tenes varias formas de resolverlo, una que responde especificamente a tu pregunta es

[...document.querySelectorAll(".cards")].lenght
Esto, desestructura tu html colection dentro de un array, y ahi tenes acceso a la propiedad lenght.

Otra, es que al array con el que haces el MAP, le tomas el largo, y en base a eso agregas una clase adicional dentro de tus cards que agregue esas propiedades.

```js
{
  cards.map(card => (
    `<div  key={card._id} className='card ${cards.lenght >=7 ? "claseMas" : null '> ...`
```

```js
let clases = `card ${cards.lenght >=7 ? "claseMas" : null}`
  {
    cards.map(card => (
        `<div  key={card._id} className=${clases} ..... `
```

Podes probar con cualquiera de esas dos opciones, creo que te van a servir.

Pero tiene pinta de ser React, asi que te recomiendo que lo hagas directamente en el map y no agregues selectores.

Tene en cuenta que solo complete el fragmento del codigo que necesita atención.